# XLPagerTabStrip Tabs not getting equal width of screen :Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, xlpagertabstrip

I am using XLPagerTabStrip, I have a Scrollview and a collectionView name Container and ButtonBarView respectively . Everything is working fine except Tab item Visibility . I want something like Tabs equaly  dividing tabs.[image]

**Parant controller code is :**

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class ParentViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

let purpleInspireColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.03, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

    // change selected bar color
    settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = .white
    settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
    settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = purpleInspireColor
    settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 2.0
    settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
    settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailiableWidth = true
    settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0
    changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
        guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
        oldCell?.label.textColor = .black
        newCell?.label.textColor = self?.purpleInspireColor
    }

}


override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let included = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IncludedViewController")
    let premium = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PremiumViewController")
    // let luxury = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LuxuryViewController")
    return [included,premium]
}
}
```

I have two tabs named Included and Premium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer on this question

go to pod file in Xcode project. Change UICollectionViewDelegate to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

class ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController: PagerTabStripViewController, PagerTabStripDataSource, PagerTabStripIsProgressiveDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout